# Source command don't export environment variable

Tags: shell

I have a shell file, test.sh

```
source /home/sea/.bashrc; echo $VAR; sleep 3
```

.bashrc

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

...

export VAR=abc
```

And execute `gnome-terminal -- bash -xc "source test.sh"` in a terminal

It outputs nothing in the end, the problem is resolved

```
+ source test.sh
++ source /home/sea/.bashrc
+++ case $- in
+++ return
++ echo

++ sleep 3
```

Comment: Make it `gnome-terminal -- bash -xc "source test.sh"` so you get an xtrace log showing you what happened during the `source` command. If that log doesn't make the problem clear, perhaps edit its contents into the question.

Comment: btw, the `export` shouldn't be needed -- it makes a variable visible to subprocesses, but here you're only using the variable in the same process, not a child.

Comment: The question is edited, echo nothing, thanks

Comment: okay, so that tells us your `.bashrc` is exiting before it gets to the `export VAR=abc` line. It's a problem with content from that bashrc file you didn't include in the question; looks like it's using a `case` to test `$-` to see if the shell is interactive or not and refusing to do anything if it isn't.

Comment: Glad to help! Since the question was solved in a way unlikely to be helpful to other readers, you might consider deleting it (or at least containing enough of your `~/.bashrc` to let others reproduce the problem without needing to work backwards from the xtrace logs).